# Django2 not connecting to Local Host

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm new to Django/Python.  I'm currently taking a beginners course and I'm having difficulty setting up my URLs and connecting to a local server. I'm using Python version: 3.7.0 and Django v.2

The command line does not give any errors (0), it tells me to go here:

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Which I believe is the local host, however the site says

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

Can anyone let me know what I'm missing I would greatly appreciate it so that I can continue on with my studying. I'm using tutorials on YT [Django Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-FTlQ7Djqc&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9ib4HsrXEYpQnTOTZE1x0uc) and the guy is using an older Django so I think that may be why I'm having trouble. He says we should still be okay to follow through even on the new version of Django.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from.import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', views.about),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def homepage(request):
    return HttpResponse('homepage')
def about(request):
    return HttpResponse('about')
```

Comment: check `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py` and verify the port when running your server. This doesn't look like an url/view problem

Comment: Hi there! It says this: ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

Comment: try it with `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']` not sure localhost is blocked in dev but it could help

Comment: Tried: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']. still not working. I'm not sure why it is empty either. I'm quite new. I just followed the steps on the tutorial and downloaded Django this morning.

Comment: Fixed it! I was able to go into the admin page and it said "You may need to add '127.0.0.1' into your ALLOWED_HOSTS section. I did that fired it up again and it works! Finally. lol

Comment: However, I just tried it again and it's loading up again and I didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. This is what was needed:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

Took me forever to figure this out. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a little modification is required in your code:
Instead of `path('about/', views.about),`
write this:

```
path('about/', views.about,name='about'),
```

after modify this line , run the server and open this http://127.0.0.1:8000/  URL  and add /about and then press enter.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/about

Hope it will work in your case